# How get which radio button was checked in details view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating exam website in vs2010 with asp.net C# 4.0,
in which I have the detailsview in questions page

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="questiondetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Horizontal" 
    Height="69px" Width="100%">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" SortExpression="question">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="5px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A)" SortExpression="a">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("a") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("a") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("a") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="B)" SortExpression="b">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("b") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("b") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("b") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C)" SortExpression="c">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("c") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("c") %>'  />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D)" SortExpression="d">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("d") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("d") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("d") %>'  />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="correctans" HeaderText="correctans" 
            SortExpression="correctans" Visible="False" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        questiondetail.DataBind();
    }
}
string userans = "Not selected";
protected void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        questiondetail.DataBind();
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)questiondetail.DataItem;

        // Create Answer object to save values
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.QuestionID = questiondetail.PageIndex.ToString();
        a.CorrectAnswer = dr.Row["correctans"].ToString();
        //get user ans

        questiondetail.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
        RadioButton r1 = questiondetail.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;
        RadioButton r2 = questiondetail.FindControl("RadioButton2") as RadioButton;
        RadioButton r3 = questiondetail.FindControl("RadioButton3") as RadioButton;
        RadioButton r4 = questiondetail.FindControl("RadioButton4") as RadioButton;

        if (r1.Checked)
        {
            userans = "A";
        }
        else if (r2.Checked)
        {
            userans = "B";
        }
        else if (r3.Checked)
        {
            userans = "C";
        }
        else if (r4.Checked)
        {
            userans = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            userans = "Not selected";
        }
        questiondetail.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly;
        a.UserAnswer = userans;

        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        al.Add(a);

        Session.Add("AnswerList", al);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblcatch.Text = ex.Message;
    }

    if (questiondetail.PageIndex == questiondetail.PageCount - 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Result.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        questiondetail.PageIndex++;
    }
    if (questiondetail.PageIndex == questiondetail.PageCount - 1)
    {
        btnnext.Text = "Finish";
    }
}
```

the problem is that on result page it shows every answer is Not selected

so how get that which radiobutton is checked in detailsview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `questiondetail.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;` and `questiondetail.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly;`

Comment: I check user ans before the data bind in next button and replace radio button with radiobuttonlist